# What does the keyboard formatted [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[U] then [A][E][Space] mean?

Tags: support

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209295/33055) has  keyboard (`<kbd></kbd>`) tagged characters as follows: 
... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> ...

Does this mean I have to press six buttons at the same time? If not what is the convention on this site? ¹

---

¹ <sub>A similar question was asked in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209293/mint-17-cinnamon-ctrlshiftu-not-letting-me-enter-unicode-symbols/209295?noredirect=1#comment355849_209295) to the answer</sub>

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just comma-separate them or something?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek That is certainly visual easier to recognize. and probably better understandable without explanation. If there is no other/better suggestion I will change it that way (and my other answers where I used just juxtaposed keyboard characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical convention used on this site is that all characters have their own `<kbd></kdb>` box and that multi-character entries are only used for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc.

If there is a "+" between two keys that means that the characters have to be typed at the same time. If there is a comma (or nothing) you type the characters one after another. I have not seen any particular convention for press and hold X  then press Y.

Typing (i.e. press and release) <kbd>A</kbd> normally results in lowercase 'a'. To get 'A' this would be represented as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. It is never <kbd>a</kbd> as the actual character on the keyboard is uppercase.

The sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> means:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> at the same time and release
- type <kbd>A</kbd>  (type means: press and release)
- type <kbd>E</kbd>
- type <kbd>Space</kbd>